# Is it possible to print the output from ogr2ogr directly to stdout?

Tags: ogr2ogr, shell

I know I can convert a Shapefile to GeoJSON as the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON outputFile.json inputFile.shp
```

Instead of writing the result of this conversion to the file `outputFile.json`, I'd like to print this result directly on `stdout`, without having to write a file on the system. Since I'm inside a bash script I know I can find alternative solutions as the following one:

```
tmpFile=$(mktemp).json
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON $tmpFile inputFile.shp
cat $tmpFile
```

However, I'd like to know if `ogr2ogr` supports printing to stdout instead of writing on files, just so I can do it in one line of code. I've searched in the `man ogr2ogr` page but it doesn't even contain the word `stdout` there. Is it possible to print the output of `ogr2ogr` directly to stdout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `/vsistdout/` [virtual filesystem](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html):

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON /vsistdout/ inputFile.shp
```